# Ragged font in FontAwesome

Tags: font-awesome

I read some articles and stackoverflow questions about font awesome. I successfully implemented it on my website but I have one big problem with it.

[Here is jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gc6sx/1/)

Here is the code

html:

```
<i class="icon-th-list font-25em"></i>&nbsp font 2.5em<br/>
<i class="icon-th-list font-2em"></i>&nbsp font 2em<br/>
```

css:

```
body {
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.font-25em {
    font-size: 2.5em !important;
}

.font-2em {
    font-size: 2em !important;
}
```

Icons with font-size 2em etc. works perfectly but when I change font size to 2.5em the font is ragged and looks awful.

Am I doing something wrong?

Please help

Comment: I' am using newest chrome and newest firefox by the way.

Comment: I think something might be wrong with your OS? It's a truetype font so it should scale smoothly. Looks fine on my computer w/newest Chrome: http://imgur.com/cwSxeB7

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what browser(s) are causing the problem, but does anything here look better for you http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/mYMnh/ ?

I changed the antialiasing to `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` and if you want to get fancy you can add a small shadow to the icon to smooth the :

```
.font-25em {
font-size: 2.5em !important;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.004);
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: It's acceptable solution but I think that using external images will be better solution. Thank for your response!